# Looping through JSON structured data

Tags: python, json, data-structures, python-3.6

I wrote a python script that connects to a sql database and returns a query. I fetch this query and loop through it to store it in a list and then write this to a JSON file.

I am currently writing a separate script that will retrieve this data from the JSON file and loop through it to only return data based on certain criteria.

The JSON format has many records that are ALMOST identical like this:

```
{
    "email": "EMAIL@HOTMAIL.COM",
    "reason_code": "PENDING",
    "product": "SWRD",
    "record_id": "0000000001"
},
{
    "email": "EMAIL@HOTMAIL.COM",
    "reason_code": "CONFIRM",
    "product": "KNFE",
    "record_id": "0000000001"
}
```

I'd like to loop through this file and return only the records that meet the following criteria into a list:

1. Check for duplicate `record_id`'s (many will have duplicate record_id's)
2. If 2 `record_id`'s are duplicate, then I only want to return the record that has `"product":"SWRD"` into arbitrary_list
3. If `record_id` is not duplicate, then return into arbitrary_list

How I've tried to tackle the problem:
I've looped through the file and stored everything in a python list. I make a copy of that list and loop through both to try and return blocks into a new list. That did not work.
It seems like I need to loop through the file and store everything into a list. Then it seems like I'd need to loop through that list, extract the first block from the list, compare it the remainder of the list, and if there is not a match, then return that block to a new list and if there is a match then go through an if-else statement based on the criteria. Then I'd take the second block and repeat this process all over again. I am just not sure how to go about accomplishing this.

So by the time I'm done, I'll have one JSON file that has no duplicate record_id's. If anyone could help me that would be great. I can post code samples if need be, but I'd have to change some of the code in order to post it online. Please let me know if you have any questions

Comment: What attempts have you made to do this. Please add it or them to your question and describe why/how it/they don't work correctly.

Comment: @martineau - I updated what I have tried and the solution that I feel like has to happen, but I am just not sure how to accomplish it.

Comment: Your verbal description is not the same as seeing the that doesn't work. In fact, if it's too long or complicated, it will be necessary you to change what you have into something much shorter. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Make a dictionary of `{record_id: {product: json_object}}`, then you can do the per-`record_id` processing based on `product`

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict

with open('input.json') as f:
     obj_list = json.load(f)

d = defaultdict(dict)
for obj in obj_list:
    d[obj['record']][obj['product']] = obj

l = []
for products in d.values():
    if 'SWRD' in products:
        l.append(products['SWRD'])
    else:
        _, product = products.popitem()  # get some other product, we don't care which
        l.append(product)

with open('output.json', 'w+') as f:
    json.dump(l, f)
```